# May, Merkel, Lagarde...is there a term for women that govern?

Tags: gender-politics

Is there a term that refers to political power held by women? A term that possibly ends with  ***[-cracy:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-cracy&allowed_in_frame=0)***

> word-forming element forming nouns meaning "rule or government by. " The connective -o- has come to be viewed as part of it. Productive in English from c. 1800.

I can't find any reference looking in [Google](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&ei=vsiPV_3aLuiegAbK9bzICw&q=women%20with%20political%20power%20&oq=women%20with%20political%20power%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...6672.13935.0.14349.29.28.0.2.2.0.436.5237.0j9j11j1j2.23.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..8.12.2645...41j0i22i30i19j30i10.VmkQyCJXFtI).

Comment: [Matriarchy?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=matriarchy+meaning&t=ffnt&ia=definition)

Comment: I hadn't realised that these ladies were rulers or governors. They are still accountable in a democracy.

Comment: [Feminocracy](http://www.usnews.com/opinion/blogs/peter-roff/2012/02/03/feminocracy-wins-in-attacks-on-susan-g-komen-foundation) refers to the leadership of the women's movement.

Comment: 'women leaders', or 'women heads of state' is the current term.

Comment: What do Merkel and Largarde have in common? What is your definition of to govern? Why do you need the term? Can you write an example sentence where the term would be used? Women that govern have many titles, prime minister, chancellor, president (if Hillary is elected), etc.

Comment: Rathony has a point.  As for the sample sentence, I suggest: Are we headed for a   ________, with May and Merkel leading two powerful countries, three out of eight justices of the U.S. Supreme Court women, and the increasing prominence of women in positions of political and economic power in many countries?  Your title could also be tweaked.

Comment: Addendum to my last comment:  There may seem to be self-interest in my suggested sentence, because my answer fits the blank, but think it is what the OP means.

Comment: Lagarde's power is different from Merkel's but it still is an example of a position typically taken by men which is now in the hands of a woman. @ab2 I think you got the point. Thanks

Comment: See [Monstrous Regimen of Women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Blast_of_the_Trumpet_Against_the_Monstruous_Regiment_of_Women).  John Knox's phrase 1558.  He didn't like Mary of Guise, regent for Mary of Scots nor Mary (Bloody Mary) of England.  But, then, Elizabeth I succeeded Mary and was not happy with Knox.

Comment: With the examples you provide I'd be inclined to go for *virago*.


http://www.thefreedictionary.com/virago

Comment: @5arx Please clarify your comment. Defintion #1 or Definition #2?

Comment: @Saturana Read your question title and body again. Do they match? You are asking one thing in the title and another in the body. What is your question? Do you know what roles Merkel and Lagarde play? What is your definition of to govern? You need to be specific when asking a question.

Comment: @ab2 it was just a fatuous quip. I meant no harm or usefulness. Oh - the first of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***gynocracy*** (alt spelling gynecocracy) fits what the OP is asking. From the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82869?redirectedFrom=gynocracy#eid)

> Women as the ruling class

Alt. ***gynecocracy***, [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82852?redirectedFrom=gynecocracy#eid)

> Government by a woman or women; female rule or mastery;
>   depreciatingly, petticoat government.

Quotation from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82869?redirectedFrom=gynocracy#eid):

> 1864   Macmillan's Mag. July 219   From a gynocracy..heaven save us
>   and all Christian communities!

The oldest form is ***gynarchy***, "government by women or a woman". See [Etomonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=g&p=33&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **gynarchy**: government by women or a woman," 1570s, from Greek gyne "woman, wife,"  from PIE *gwen- "woman" (see queen) + -arkhe "rule" (see archon).
>   Synonymous gynaecocracy (from Greek gynaikokratia) and gyneocracy are
>   attested from 1610s; gynocracy is from 1728.

***matriarchy*** is close, but not quite what the OP is asking for. From the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115017?redirectedFrom=matriarchy#eid)

> A form of social organization in which the mother or oldest female is
>   the head of the family, and descent and relationship are reckoned
>   through the female line; government or rule by a woman or women. Also
>   (in Cultural Anthropol.): a culture or community in which such a
>   system prevails; a family, society, organization, etc., dominated by a
>   woman or women.

The difference appears to be that in a matriarchy, the females of the family line hold power in the family and by extension a prominent place in the society, whereas in a gynocracy women hold power as individuals, not as family elders who are women.

Comment: This is for rulers, not heads of mixed-gender governments.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Wait 20 years. :)  But I'll poke around further.

Comment: Lagarde is different from Merkel. She doesn't rule nor govern anything. She is just sitting there doing nothing except for travelling a lot and making some speeches, but she doesn't have any power to make any decision. Obama and his secretaries make a decision. The OP's question is as unclear as it gets.

Comment: @Rathony - my question is about women with political power, whatever their position! The above answer shows that my question is as clear as it gets! Thank you!!

Comment: If the successor to Merkel,  May, et al is not guaranteed to be a woman, is the government still a gynocracy?

Comment: @user662852  No government is a gynocracy nor is likely to ever be.   But, compared to my childhood, where there was one woman U.S. senator (Margaret Chase Smith), a woman president or a woman Prime Minister was unthinkable and  ["kinder, küche, kicher"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinder,_K%C3%BCche,_Kirche) was the only domain of women, there is a trend towards gynocracy.  What would be the term for a 50/50 split of power and influence?  I think that is what most people would like to see, but the fact that the OP's question is interesting is proof of far women have to go.

Comment: If the OP writes an opinion piece "is this the start of a new gynocracy?", fair enough. If the OP uses this word as an offhand description of the fact that Merkel is a woman, there is a risk of alienating the reader as I do not believe the ruling class is generically women at this time. There does not have to be a single English word for every case. A 50-50 split could be a meritocracy, it could reflect patronage, or a government with set asides for certain demographic classes (the canonical example Malaysia's "Bumiputra" policy though this is not on gender)

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question literally, the word is **governess**, which derives from Old French, and previously referred to a female ruler:

> **governess**:
>   *noun*
>   (Especially in former times) a woman employed to teach children in a private household.
>
> **Origin**
>   Middle English (originally *governeress*, denoting a female ruler): from Old French *governeresse*, feminine of *governeour* 'governor', from Latin *gubernator*, from *gubernare* (see govern).

From: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/governess)

Comment: P.S.  Does the USA have any female State Governors?

Comment: http://usconservatives.about.com/od/thinkersanddoers/tp/List-Of-Female-Conservative-Governors-In-The-United-States.htm

Comment: @TrevorD Yes.  Hassan, Martinez, Fallin, Brown, Raimondo, and Haley.  [Wikipedia, Current US Governors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_governors).  No one would ever call them governesses.